# 200 column table affect performance?

Tags: sql

i wonder if it will have a big performance effect to have a table that contain only 1 row that include all settings if that row had 200 + columns

Comment: Try it and find out?

Comment: hi, thanks for suggestion actually remaking all would take me about 1 week of work for a simple test its a pretty long time i come here to have some knowledge from most experimented coder than me.

Comment: If the intent is to denormalize, then updates suffer because you update the entire table versus a single value in a definition table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One row with 200 columns is not going to have a performance impact. It's more of a maintenance issue because when you have to add a setting you need to add a new column. It's generally better to have 200 rows. You only need to think about performance when you're joining lots of tables or have 100,000 rows plus... also depends on your definition of performance.

Comment: thanks actually my setting table have 1 row that contain about 75 column that contain 1 setting in each column. Adding column is something i do pretty easely but was wondering only if making a select * from 1 row with 200 column will have a better or worst performance result than doing a select * on a table that have 200 rows with 1 settings in each of the rows

Comment: Performance of both will be inconsequential. There is effectively no difference. Yes adding a column is relatively easy but you also need to add to your application (or whatever) to use it, and you also need to populate it. Seriously consider the row approach, not the column approach. The only advantage with the column approach is that you can have a specific data type for a config.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern database servers can handle table sizes much larger than that. For example, SQL Server non-wide tables can have up to 1,024 columns, and wide tables can have up to 30,000.

How you build your indexes and write your queries will generally have much more of an impact on performance than having a large data set.